# Create a FocusTime in GCalendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

how I can create a focus time in GCalendar per script. I have created this scipt but I get a error back. Does anyone use why I my understanding is correct the syntax is OK:

```
function myFunction() {
  //Is is working
  var event1 = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('MyTimeSlot',  new Date('Juni 01, 2022 20:00:00 UTC'),  new Date('Juni 01, 2022 21:00:00 UTC'));

  // Error: ReferenceError: CalendarEvent is not defined
  var event2 = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(">>>MyTimeSlot with FOCUS TIME<<<", new Date('Juni 01, 2022 20:00:00 UTC'), new Date('Juni 01, 2022 21:00:00 UTC'), {type: CalendarEvent.EventType.FOCUS_TIME});

  event1.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.PALE_BLUE);
  event2.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.PALE_RED);
}
```

Greetings

Comment: **I get a error back**  And the error is what exactly

Answer (score 0):

The error on `event2` is because you are creating a `Focus Time` event.

**Update from comment**

> - Do I understand correctly? It does not work?
>
> Yes, the eventType parameter, as mentioned on the [Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) documentation is a read-only parameter.

There is already a feature request reported on Google's Issue Tracker for this, you can go there and star the issue to get updates on it:

> [Create programmatically Focus Time via the API CalendarApp coding in Google Script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206630110?pli=1)

Comment: Do I understand correctly? It does not work?

Comment: Yes, the `eventType` parameter, as mentioned on the [Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) documentation is a read-only parameter.